# Running multiple tensorflow sessions subsequently

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, gunicorn

I'm developing a simple REST controller using gunicorn and flask.

At each REST call, I execute the following code

```
@app.route('/objects', methods=['GET'])
def get_objects():
    video_title = request.args.get('video_title')
    video_path = "../../video/" + video_title
    cl.logger.info(video_path)
    start = request.args.get('start')
    stop = request.args.get('stop')
    scene = [start, stop]

    frames = images_utils.extract_frames(video_path, scene[0], scene[1], 1)
    cl.logger.info(scene[0]+" "+scene[1])
    objects = list()
    ##objects
    model = GenericDetector('../resources/open_images/frozen_inference_graph.pb', '../resources/open_images/labels.txt')
    model.run(frames)
    for result in model.get_boxes_and_labels():
        if result is not None:
            objects.append(result)

    data = {'message': {
        'start_time': scene[0],
        'end_time': scene[1],
        'path': video_path,
        'objects':objects,
    }, 'metadata_type': 'detection'}

    return jsonify({'status': data}), 200
```

This code runs a tensorflow frozen model as follows:

```
class GenericDetector(Process):

    def __init__(self, model, labels):
        # ## Load a (frozen) Tensorflow model into memory.
        self.detection_graph = tf.Graph()
        with self.detection_graph.as_default():
            od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            with tf.gfile.GFile(model, 'rb') as fid:
                serialized_graph = fid.read()
                od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
                tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

        self.boxes_and_labels = []

        # ## Loading label map
        with open(labels) as f:
            txt_labels = f.read()
            self.labels = json.loads(txt_labels)


    def run(self, frames):
        tf.reset_default_graph()
        with self.detection_graph.as_default():
            config = tf.ConfigProto()
            config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
            with tf.Session(graph=self.detection_graph, config=config) as sess:

                image_tensor = self.detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
                # Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected.
                detection_boxes = self.detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
                # Each score represent how level of confidence for each of the objects.
                detection_scores = self.detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
                detection_classes = self.detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
                num_detections = self.detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

                i = 0
                for frame in frames:

                    # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
                    image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame, axis=0)

                    # Actual detection.
                    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
                        [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections], \
                        feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})

                    boxes = np.squeeze(boxes)
                    classes = np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32)
                    scores = np.squeeze(scores)

                    for j, box in enumerate(boxes):
                        if all(v == 0 for v in box):
                            continue

                        self.boxes_and_labels.append(
                            {
                                "ymin": str(box[0]),
                                "xmin": str(box[1]),
                                "ymax": str(box[2]),
                                "xmax": str(box[3]),
                                "label": self.labels[str(classes[j])],
                                "score": str(scores[j]),
                                "frame":i
                            })
                    i += 1
            sess.close()
    def get_boxes_and_labels(self):
        return self.boxes_and_labels
```

Everything seems to work as excepted, but once I send a second request to my server, my GPU ( a GTX 1050 ) goes out of memory:

> ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating
>   tensor of shape [3,3,256,256] and type float

If I try to make a call after that, it works most of the time. Sometimes it will work on subsequent calls too. I tried executing the GenericDetector on a separate Process ( Making GEnericDetector hereditate Process ), but it did not help. I read that once the process that executes the REST GET is dead, the memory of the GPU should be freed, so I also tried adding a sleep(30) after the execution of the tensorflow model, with no luck. Wham am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that Tensorflow allocates the memory for the process not the Session, closing the session is not enough (even if you put the `allow_growth option`).

> The first is the allow_growth option, which attempts to allocate only as much GPU memory based on runtime allocations: it starts out allocating very little memory, and as Sessions get run and more GPU memory is needed, we extend the GPU memory region needed by the TensorFlow process. **Note that we do not release memory, since that can lead to even worse memory fragmentation.**

There is an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17048) on TF github with some solutions , you could for example decorate your run method with the `RunAsCUDASubprocess` proposed in the thread.

Comment: I found the solution in your issue link by using:

            sess.close()
            cuda.select_device(0)
            cuda.close()

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you are trying to fit into the GPU something bigger than the memory you have available. Maybe you can reduce the number of parameters somewhere in your model in order for it to be lighter?